# Does events are also copied when you clone any element in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Does events are also copied when you clone any element in jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

By default, no. However the `clone()` method does accept some boolean parameters which indicates whether the events and data on the cloned elements, and optionally their children, should be cloned too.

For more information see the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Answer (score 0):

Using clone() method, we can create clone of any element but the default implementation of the clone() method doesn't copy events unless you tell the clone() method to copy the events. The clone() method takes a parameter, if you pass true then it will copy the events as well.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#btnClone").bind('click', function(){
         $('#dvClickme').clone(true).appendTo('body');
    });
```